# Eigenvectors of Period-translation matrix for Hill's equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given Hill's equation $\ddot{x}+k(t)x=0$ such that $k$ is T-periodic ($k(t)=k(t+T)$). We can easily see that if $x(t)$ is a solution of this equation so is $x(t+T)$ (although this doesn't mean $x(t)$ is periodic with $T$)

given two solution $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ we can write $x_1(t+T)=Ax_1(t)+Bx_2(t)$,
or in vector form:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t)  \\x_2(t) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1(t+T)  \\x_2(t+T) \end{pmatrix}=T \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t)  \\x_2(t) \end{pmatrix}
\tag1$$

Now a statement in my textbook says that we can write the eigenvectors of matrix $T$ such that $$Ty(t)=e^qy(t)=y(t+T)\tag2$$  in the following way:

$$y(t)=e^{\frac{qt}{T}}u(t)\tag3$$

where $u(t)$ **is** a periodic function! 
$$u(t+T)=u(t)\tag4$$

why is this so? How can one show that we can write our function $y(t)$ in this way?

ps: It can also be shown that $\det(T)=1$, I don't know if this is of any help tho.

Comment: Looks like they have used [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory#Floquet's_theorem).

Comment: I've added equation numbers to the main steps. It seems that you have problems with (4), the periodicity. Are the other steps clear, how you get to (2) and that (3) is a definition?

Comment: My main problem is with step (2)